# Coverting all the list elements to string using Python?

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list:

```
roll = [1, 2, 3]
```

For converting each of the element into a string, can we directly do `roll = str(roll)` rather that iterating over it and calling `str()` on each element? Is this a correct way?

I am new to Python, any hint in the right direction will do!

Comment: no, you `roll_str = [str(n) for n in roll]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That wouldn't work, since that would convert the *entire* list into one string:

```
roll = [1, 2, 3]
roll = str(roll)
print(roll)
# Prints [1, 2, 3]
print(type(roll))
# Prints <class 'str'>
```

You can instead use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), to convert each item in the list one by one:

```
roll = [1, 2, 3]
roll = [str(r) for r in roll]
print(roll)
# Prints ['1', '2', '3']
print(type(roll))
# Prints <class 'list'>
```

Answer (score 2):

Thinking in terms of types, the original variable you have is of type `List[int]` (`[1, 2, 3]`).

When using the `str` function, the result is an element of type `str` (aka `'[1, 2, 3]'`), but that's not the result that you want since you want to convert each individual element in the list to `str`, which makes the desired type to be `List[str]` (`['1', '2', '3']`).

In python, there are several canonical ways to apply a function to each individual element:

#### List Comprehension

```py
new_roll = [str(x) for x in roll] # ['1', '2', '3']
```

This method is the simplest. It is basically a one-liner that does the followings:

```py
new_roll = []
for x in roll:
    new_roll.append(str(x))
```

Notice that the original variable `roll` won't be mutated since it is creating a new list.

#### Map

Another way to do the same thing is by using the `map` function in python. However for efficiency reason, the type of the output is of type `Map[str]` instead of type `List[str]`.

```py
roll_map = map(str, roll)
for x in roll_map:
    print(x)
```

It is basically doing the followings:

```py
roll = [1, 2, 3]
for x in roll:
    str_x = str(x)
    print(str_x)
```

Notice that no new list has been created in order to save memory. This method is generally applicable when you need the result of a function applied to a list (or an iterator in general) but you do not want to store the results of the function application (to save memory).

A common hack to obtain a list via the `map` function is by `list(map(str, roll))`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be done without iterating over it using loop in following way:

```
roll = list(map(str, roll))
```